# To generate the results of the Android JUnit test case once the test has finished running

Tags: java, android, excel, junit, robotium

I have an Android JUnit test case that uses Robotium to automate the entire functional flow of my android app. However, what i want is, once the test has finished running, I need to write the results to a text file, preferably to an excel sheet, where it writes a "Pass" or "Fail" against the different test cases mentioned.

Anticipate your help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it if you use eclipse clicking on Export (see image below)

[image]

I'm searching a way to have this report launching a command from dos prompt. I found this:

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

but I haven't used it yet because I'm having problem in converting Robotium project in Maven Project.